# Problems with icons in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

Good night. I have a problem, I installed Lubuntu operating system, but I have a question as I put the icons on the desktop, icons such as trash, home, etc ... 
I would also like to know how to enter the browser window as administrator.

Comment: Please make the question more clear.

Comment: Indeed, it's very hard to interpret "as I put the icons on the desktop, icons such as trash, home, etc" as a question.

Comment: what version of lubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 12.04

Comment: Just to clarify for others' benefit, by "browser window" it looks like you mean a file browser e.g. PCMan, because doing that with a *web browser* would be a *really bad idea* (and unnecessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the root access in the File manager PCMANFM, you can open it and the option to access a folder (Change to root) is in the **TOOLS MENU**. Select "Open Curent Folder as Root" and type in the password. In some cases you might get an error about the root not working. You can skip this since it will actually work.

[image]

For the **TRASH** icon you can do the following:

1. Right click the desktop and select **Create New..** --> **Blank File**

   [image]
2. Name it whatever you want. Just open the file afterwards and put this inside:

   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Contains removed files
   EmptyIcon=trashcan_empty
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Icon=trashcan_full
   Name=Trash
   Type=Link
   URL=trash:/

This will create the Trash icon which you can access the Trash folder to either verify, restore or remove items.

Answer (score 1):

Well your question seens difficult to understand but from what i comprehend you want to do 2 things

1. Add desktops icons like Thrash , home folder etc
2. Administrator rights while using Lubuntu's file manager `pcmanfm`.

#### Solution for 1

Type this in terminal
`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` 
then press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`

Then navigate to  apps ----> nautilus ----> desktop

You might find something lke this
[image]

[image]

Just change the `No value`  to what you want and click on the check box (the second one should be an example)

#### Solution for 2

For administrator rights for the file manager `pcmanfm`

type
`gksu pcmanfm`

You could also add a .desktop shortcut for the admin privileges

Right click your desktop. Choose `New > Blank file`. When the dialog opens, enter the name
`pcmanfm-root.desktop`

and click OK.

Open the file with leafpad and enter the following (use copy and paste)

> [Desktop Entry]
> Type=Application
> Icon=system-file-manager
> Name=PCManFM Super User
> Comment=Browse the file system and manage the files
> Categories=FileManager;FileManager;X-MandrivaLinux-System-FileTools;
> Exec=gksu -l pcmanfm /root
> StartupNotify=truegksu pcmanfm /root
> Terminal=false
> MimeType=x-directory/normal;inode/directory;
> Encoding=UTF-8
> X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.11

Save and exit. This will create an icon on your desktop.

Comment: Ok I think I have not been able to explain. What I want is to put the respective icons trash, home, etc on the desktop.

I also want to know how to enter the file manager, is that in Ubuntu's Nautilus, but not as open in Lubuntu and a root to modify some things in the root directory. I'm using Lubuntu 12.04

Comment: @mcepeda14 so my first part is correct

Comment: @mcepeda14 edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I did what you said but still I have the same problem, check the icons and have not seen, will not know if a system failure. Although it looks better without icons, but I will continue trying with the window manager

Comment: @mcepeda14 try `Ubuntu tweak` and see

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + A while on the desktop & if your mouse is functional, go ahead and right click a desktop icon and unselect "Stick to Current Postition" and select Snap to grid. 
This worked for me.